# Repair C Drive without formatting

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, filesystem-corruption

Is there a way to temporarily repair a C drive (SSD) without the need to format? I tried running `chkdsk C: /r /f /x` both in normal mode and in safe mode, but I kept getting the message

```
Cannot lock current drive.

Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Would you like to schedule this volume to be
checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N)
```

Naturally, when I typed in `Y` and restarted, I get the message `Scanning and repairing C:`, but I get this [error message again on restart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPO6R.png) I also tried the powershell command `Repair-Volume -DriveLetter C -OfflineScanAndFix` with different switches to it, but all it does is report `NoErrorsFound`, when there are clearly errors in the C drive. Any suggestions or tools which can help fix this issue? I understand that any suggestions will not completely fix this issue, but I just want a temporary fix so that the error message can go away.

This issue only came up yesterday, when I was surfing Google Chrome and the computer crashed. When I first started running chkdsk, it told me that there were some corrupted Google Chrome User Data files, which was why I uninstalled Chrome today. However, even after doing that, my C drive still reports a problem, which is why I find it perplexing. There are also 4 [system files in the C drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJxaa.png) which only started appearing yesterday, which can't seem to go away no matter what I do to them.

I am also asking here instead of the Windows Forum because I find the answers there to be completely generic and very much unhelpful.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like significant filesystem damage. I'm assuming you don't have backups. It's time to start from scratch.

Avoid writing to the disk if possible. Ideally, don't boot from this disk - connect it to another PC or boot Linux from USB. This will ensure no further data loss.

Prepare additional drive and make a copy of all files you need. Then disconnect the backup drive (to avoid mishaps) and reinstall Windows from scratch.

Once you have the system up and running, figure out a reliable backup strategy. It should be automated and reliably restorable in a reasonable time frame. I can recommend Veeam Agent. Its free version lets you back up entire system, including Windows, automatically on schedule without interrupting your work. Restoration can be performed using a recovery USB, it's quite fast and foolproof.

Answer (score -1):

first those 4 files: they belong to the OS. Keep 'm.
Try from a command prompt: **sfc /scannow**.
If you get errors try again with sfc until no errors show up.
And afterwards: **DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth**

That repair option in windows just forgo for now.

Comment: If the filesystem is damaged trying to repair Windows can make things worse.